# how to get value from .ejs file and use it ni a .js file

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I have a **login.ejs** file I want to use the username entered in the textbox in a **.js** file.

login.ejs contain following **HTML**

```
<h1>Log in</h1>
<div>
<label>Username:</label>
<input type="text" id="username" name="uname" /><br/>
</div>
<div>
<label>Password:</label>
<input type="password" id="password" name="pw" />
</div>
<div>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</div>
```

and the **code** in **.js** file where I want to use that value is

```
if(username==teacher)
{
//some thing
}
else if(username==student)
{
//some thing
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put this in the `head` of your ejs file, before loading the `a.js` file

```
 "<script > var username<%= title %> </script>"
```

This will define the variable username with the parameter passed to the ejs file, and you would be able to access it in any js file linked to the page

Comment: -how can I link the **.js** file to the page?

Comment: @Sameel.. Just like u do in html page `<script src='pathToJs'></script>`